# POSIX epoch format to timezone using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

I came across use where I'm getting time in **POSIX** epoch format. I want to convert it to local date of given timezone. but momentjs is giving different result.

`moment .unix(1700742300) .tz('America/New_York') .format('');`

Result: '2023-11-23T07:25:00' but actual answer has to be '2023-11-23T07:15:00.000'

Comment: I do not understand what you say it should be 7:15. To me the 7:25 seems correct.

Comment: `new Date(1700742300*1e3).toLocaleString('en-gb',{timeZone:'America/New_York'})` gives "23/11/2023, 07:25:00". Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: Because the reference from I get this epoch convert this to ` 7:15`. The provider of this is GDS or flightaware